# JavaScript throws 'cannot read property ... of undefined' error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a basic JQuery app which loads images from Flickr, adds them to an array of  jQuery objects, sequentially adds them to the DOM, fades them in, and fades them out in a 3 second cycle. However, in my `displayImage` function, I cannot use .hide(), .fadeIn() or .fadeOut() because it throws an 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fadeIn' of undefined' error. Here is my code, both the JS and the HTML:

```
var main = function(){
"use strict";
var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cats&format=json&jsoncallback=?";
//Creates the empty array of jQuery image objects
var images = [];
$.getJSON(url, function(flickrResponse){
    flickrResponse.items.forEach(function (photo){
        var $img = $("<img>").hide();

        $img.attr("src", photo.media.m);
        //Populates the images array with jQuery objects defined from the Flickr JSON request
        images.push($img);

        // $("main .photos").append($img);
        // $img.fadeIn();
    });
});

function displayImage(imgIndex) {
    var $displayedImg = images[imgIndex];
    $(".photos").fadeOut('slow');
    $(".photos").empty();
    $(".photos").append($displayedImg);
    $displayedImg.fadeIn('slow');
    //Function which recursively calls 'displayImage' every three seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
        imgIndex = imgIndex + 1;
        displayImage(imgIndex);
    }, 3000);
}
displayImage(0);
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

And

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Flickr App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>

  </header>

  <main>
    <div class = "photos">
    </div>
  </main>


  <footer>
  </footer>

   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 </body>
```

Any ideas what might be undefined? Note that the `var $img = $("<img>").hide();` line in the `$.getJSON`request doesn't throw the undefined error!

Thanks very much!

EDIT:

I've also tried to make a synchronous request to fetch the JSON, to make sure it's loaded before the `displayImage` function is called, and still it throws the same errors:

```
var main = function(){
"use strict";
var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cats&format=json&jsoncallback=?";
var images = [];
//THIS IS WHAT HAS CHANGED
$.ajax({url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(flickrResponse){
    flickrResponse.items.forEach(function (photo){
        var $img = $("<img>").hide();

        $img.attr("src", photo.media.m);

        images.push($img);

    });
}});

function displayImage(imgIndex) {
    var $displayedImg = images[imgIndex];
    $(".photos").fadeOut('slow');
    $(".photos").empty();
    $(".photos").append($displayedImg);
    $displayedImg.fadeIn('slow');

    setTimeout(function(){
        imgIndex = imgIndex + 1;
        displayImage(imgIndex);
    }, 3000);
}
displayImage(0);
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the JSON to return before you try to `displayImage(0)`. The JSON request is asynchronous, so your call to `displayImage` is happening before any JSON has been returned.

I recommend stepping through with a Javascript debugger to better understand what’s going on. You would see then that `images` is empty, and therefore `$displayedImg` is undefined.

Comment: It makes sense, but how do I stop the displayImage function from executing until the JSON has been returned? And thank you for the answer!

Comment: Why not call `displayImage` at the end of your JSON callback? Regarding your update, that’s still not synchronous. Calls for JSON are inherently asynchronous, that’s why there’s the `success` callback, it’s activated when the request returns.